# Post object is null - angular, .NET Core

Tags: .net, .net-core, angular9

I have post request in angular:

```
  postHistory(filter: HistoryFilter): Observable<History[]> {
    console.log("filter service: ", filter);
    return this._http.post<History[]>('api/history/HistoryByFilter', filter);
  }
```

and I have controller method:

```
        [HttpPost("[action]")]
        public IActionResult HistoryByFilter(HistoryFilter filter)
        {
           var test = filter;


        }
```

in log there is an object that is not null, but when I check in controller it is null. I don't know how to fix this?

I tried to passed data by body but it didn't help.

Comment: Is your code complete? You doesn't have `return` statement in your action.

Comment: This is just one line of my code. This is not whole method. The case is the object filter is null though I pass this object from angular and there this object is exist.

Comment: You are also missing your root url. How do you host you .net core app? Is this on localhost? Please add this before `api/history/HistoryByFilter`

Comment: If this was a routing error the action wouldn't get called at all. What is the JSON payload? Does it match the `HistoryFilter` class in C#? If it doesn't the parameter will be null. Use either Fiddler or the Network tab in the browser's developer tools to see what's actually sent to the server

Comment: If the payload is JSON you should add `[FromBody]` to the action's parameter.  [This article explains why](https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: I checked in POSTMAN and it works. I don't have problem with routing

Comment: Is the payload JSON? Try using  `public IActionResult HistoryByFilter([FromBody] HistoryFilter filter)`

Comment: When I Try in POSTMAN I used JSON but in angular no.

Comment: But I tried changed this and pass object as body in angular and then use JSON and [FromBody] in controller but it didn't work